# Why there is a delay in CSS animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Why there is a delay in `CSS` `animation`?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#scrolltoblock").on("click", (e) => {
    let yBlockOffset = $("#scrolltome").offset().top;
    let headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    let margins = parseInt($("#scrolltome").css('margin-top'));
    let totalScroll = yBlockOffset - headerHeight - margins;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 1000);
    $("#scrolltome").css("-animation", " target-fade-b 5s");
    $("#scrolltome").css("-webkit-animation", " target-fade-b 5s");
    $("#scrolltome").css("-moz-animation", " target-fade-b 5s");
    $("#scrolltome").css("-o-animation", " target-fade-b 5s");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

#scrolltome {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes target-fade-b {
  from {
    border: 100px;
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* [1] */
  to {
    border: double;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes target-fade-b {
  from {
    border: 100px;
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* [1] */
  to {
    border: double;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes target-fade-b {
  from {
    border: 100px;
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* [1] */
  to {
    border: double;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes target-fade-b {
  from {
    border: 100px;
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* [1] */
  to {
    border: double;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"><a id="scrolltoblock" href="#scrolltoyellowblock">Click for Css Effect</a></div>
<div></div>
<div id="scrolltome"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @dcn please do provide html too.

Comment: @HardenRahul I have edited the question.

Comment: You mean a delay except for the 1000 ms - 1 sec that you set in your animation?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis Yes, the animation is delayed hope 1s.

Comment: the border is doubled after some time

Comment: Could you provide the css rulea for the 5s class? Or delete this class and check if your problem changes?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I didn't get you

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis If you want to make any changes here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euufuvxz/)

Comment: What border are you talking about? The class 5s creates an effect in the yellow section. If you delete it this effect won't take place but what exactly is what you want to happen?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis the yellow section has the effect of 5s, I am talking about that. Why does it start after some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly the final effect you want to achieve maybe this syntax comes close to your endgoal.

```
 $(function() {
  $("#scrolltoblock").on("click", (e) => {
    let yBlockOffset = $("#scrolltome").offset().top;
    let headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    let margins = parseInt($("#scrolltome").css('margin-top'));
    let totalScroll = yBlockOffset - headerHeight - margins;

        $("#scrolltome").css("-animation"," target-fade-b 1.5s");

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 900);
  });
 });
```

If it is close to what you want you could play a little with the value of the time 1.5 sec and animation delay (900) until you get the best analogy for you. I updated the fiddle too with the answer in case you want to play a little with it.

Comment: I updated the fiddle too with the answer in case you want to play a little with it. **Can I get the fiddle with additions to my code?**

Comment: @DCN Sorry I thought with the update would be the new instance. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/euufuvxz/4/

Comment: Sorry for late, but if I keep only `1.5s`, then it will be more or less useless of the animation! At least the animation should be of 5s.

Comment: And I saw your code, you removed `e.preventDefault()`. Is it not necessary?

Comment: Any updates with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608274/why-there-is-a-delay-in-css-animation/47610459#comment82193123_47610459), sir?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what your problem is. Is you set the 5sec delay for the second effect it will just take that time to start and be completed. The prevent default is necessairy and good practise when your target has more event on their click event. You can use it or not depending in the case it's up to you. For the specefic code you have provided it is not necessairy.